# FileNet retrieving the GUID without SQL Query?

Tags: filenet-content-engine

I am working on a program that upload PDF files to FileNet, and was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the GUID without running a SQL Query. I also tried Retrieving a Document (fetchInstance) from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/document_procedures.htm without the new Id part of the code and that did not work.

```
public class DocIdGenerator implements EventActionHandler {
private static final String DS = "ECMSvcsXA";
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "Insert into dbo.ICNLegalDocID_S (object_id) values (?)";
private static final String SELECT_SQL = "Select DocId From dbo.ICNLegalDocID_S Where object_id = ?";

@Override
public void onEvent(ObjectChangeEvent event, Id subscriptionId)
throws EngineRuntimeException {
// Get the Document object from the event
ObjectStore os = event.getObjectStore();
Id objectId = event.get_SourceObjectId();
PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter();
pf.addIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, "DocumentID", null));
pf.addIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, PropertyNames.VERSION_SERIES, null));
Document sourceDoc = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, objectId, pf);
Properties props = sourceDoc.getProperties();
String documentId = props.getStringValue("DocumentID");
VersionSeries vs = sourceDoc.get_VersionSeries();
Id versionSeriesId = vs.get_Id();

if (documentId == null || documentId.isEmpty()) {
// Get the JNDI Context to lookup DataSource and Insert the objectId to get the auto generated docId
Context ctx;
DataSource ds;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(DS);
con = ds.getConnection();
ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
ps.setString(1, versionSeriesId.toString());
rs = ps.executeQuery();
BigDecimal docId = null;
if (rs.next()) {
// Document Id already exists
docId = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
} else {
// Document Id doesn't exist inert to get it
ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.setString(1, versionSeriesId.toString());
ps.executeUpdate();
rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
docId = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
}
}
props.putValue("DocumentID", docId.toString());
sourceDoc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
if (e instanceof EngineRuntimeException) {
throw (EngineRuntimeException)e;
} else {
ErrorStack es = new ErrorStack("DocIdGeneratorSub", new ErrorRecord[] {new ErrorRecord(e)});
throw new EngineRuntimeException(es);
}
} finally {
close(con, ps, rs);
}
}
}

private void close(Connection con, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs) {
if (rs != null) {
try {
rs.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// Ignore
}
}

if (ps != null) {
try {
ps.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// Ignore
}
}

if (con != null) {
try {
con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// Ignore
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand what to you trying to do.
When you create new document instance (`Document doc = Factory.Document.newInstance()`) and invoke `doc.save(Refresh.REFRESH)` options, FileNet inserts new DB record for document instance, generate new ID and populate it backward to the document instance on your side.

So, to get Id for new Document you just need to call `doc.getId()` to get it.

As I understand from your sample, you try to use event handler, If you invoke handler on the event `before creation`, you don't have any Id at this time, you cant try to handle the event `after document creation`.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, you can also supply an Id upon creation, and avoid the round-trip required to obtain an auto-generated one.  This is very helpful if you are using batching APIs.